# Two meanings of applications tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

The applications tag contains two different sorts of questions:

1. What are the (real world) application of [a concept]?
2. I have [a problem] and it is not immediately obvious how to solve it or formulate it exactly, but it looks mathematical. Can you help?

Personally, I enjoy questions of kind 2, but find those of kind 1 to not be so interesting. Further, these two types of questions are very different from each other.

Questions of type 2 are rarer and are often (though not nearly always) written in a poor way, since the questioner typically does not have the knowledge to give a proper and nice mathematical formulation. Some examples: [Simple lowpass frequency response](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220/), [How can I curve a test grade knowing only the average and the highest score?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666108), [How large rectangles fit on canvas](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1536611), [Clash of Clans. What's the total time to train?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1530280), [How to plan a ride by several buses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1520735), [How can I curve a test grade knowing only the average and the highest score?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666108)

Is there an different tag for either of these two question types, or can we create one?

---

There is also the misuse of the tag where it is added to random mathematical questions, since they apply a concept or come from a physical problem but are presented as, say, integrals sans context.

Comment: The second one looks like [mathematical-modeling] tag.